# Cockney accent: "a" or "an" before words starting with h? How about "the"?

Tags: articles, accent, elision

How do you say "a help" (or the indefinite article followed by another word that starts with a normally non-silent h) with a Cockney accent, which drops word-initial h's? So would you say a elp or an elp? How about "the help"? "Duh elp" or "dee elp"?